# problem with understanding logarithm

Tags: logarithms

Could anyone explain why this is true?$$\log_{a}{b^{\log_{a}c}} = \log_{a}{c}\log_{a}{b}$$

I think it's related to $a^{\log_{a}{b}}=b$ but I can't link it ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
$$M\log_{a}{x}=\log_{a}{(x^M)}$$

Comment: so just $\log_{a}{c}\log_{a}{b} = \log_{a}{b^{\log_{a}{c}}}$ , assuming $M=\log_{a}{c}$ ?

Comment: Yes,That's my mean